# Does std::scoped_lock lock after being declared?

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++17

In the code below will `part1` be in the mutually exclusive section **too** ?

```
std::mutex m;
void foo ()
{
   //....do steps part 1....

   std::scoped_lock lock(m);

   //....do steps part 2....

}
```

See relevant post [blog](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2019/01/13/c17-stdscoped_lock/)

Comment: Can you explain why you think it might be?

Answer (score 4):

If you read the documentation for [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock), it states that the lock takes ownership of the mutex when the lock is created and releases ownership when the lock is destroyed.

In your case, `part 1` is literally outside the scope of the lock and, thus, exclusive access is not enforced in `part 1`, but is enforced in `part 2`.

And, just in case this is causing confusion, the "scope" of a variable is from creation to destruction.

Answer (score 2):

No, part1 will not be in the mutually exclusive section.  The `scoped_lock` object is not in [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) yet while part1 is running.  The mutex will not be locked until the `scoped_lock` object is created, which happens *after* part1 is finished but *before* part2 begins.  Code statements execute in the order they are written (for the most part, not counting how the compiler may rearrange things for optimizations, order of evaluations, etc).

Comment: ***Code statements execute in the order they are written.*** Life would be much easier, if that was the case. CPU pipeline and compiler optimizer just keep us night owls busy.